# Messed up nodejs installation

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, nodejs

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed nodejs, but I think I may have messed up somewhere along the way. I'm trying to start an ionic app with `ionic serve --devappcd`. Then I get this error message:

```
ionic-app-scripts serve --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser

[INFO] Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.

This package is required for this command to work properly. 
The package provides a CLI utility, but the ionic-app-scripts binary was not found in your PATH.

? Install @ionic/app-scripts? Yes
npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mick/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/4f/4a'
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mick/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/a5/ef'
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mick/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/4f/c4'
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mick/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/6e/d0'
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mick/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/1e/e1'
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mick/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/74/2e'
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mick/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/68/37'
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mick/.npm/_logs/2019-04-06T12_04_23_552Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Is it possible to uninstall nodejs and start again?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
sudo npm cache clean --force --unsafe-perm
```

Then after that repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have proper permission access on global packages.

1. Uninstall node js completely
2. Install node (i prefer snap)

   sudo snap install node --channel=10/stable --classic

Follow [this guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) to allow your global packages correct permission. Steps here

```
cd
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'

nano .profile
# add at the end of .profile file
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

# save, then reload by running.
source ~/.profile
```

now you should install ionic cli (**don't use sudo**) and try to run the project.